# Onclick of hyperlink modal popup window in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm working on a project where the requirement is onclick of a hyperlink the page will show as a modal popup.
How to do that ?

Comment: Set `target="_blank"` attribute to the link ..?

Comment: @Teemu isn't _blank for a new tab? I guess they are looking for modals

Comment: Google 'Javascript modal popup'. There are hundreds of libraries which can do this, most of which will have tutorial guides on their use. If you then have a specific problem *with the code you've written*, start a new SO question remembering to include the code within it.

Comment: @LelioFaieta That depends on the user preferences. If OP is looking for a "modal", I think they should at least mention it in the question.

Comment: @Rory in my href there's a page link suppose www.google.com. i want to show that link as a modal popup 
i know "<a href="javascript:window.open('some.html', 'yourWindowName', 'width=200,height=150');">Test</a> " using this i can easily achieve my requirement. But i want modal popup to open that page

Comment: @RikaDas You can't show that page in a "modal pop-up", you need a regular separate pop-up window, which is not modal, though.  If it's another third-party page, you've to check `X-Frame-Option` header, it might limit the use of the page in an iframe, which is practically the only option to show a third-party page in a "modal".

Comment: @Teemu is correct. There will be no way to display google.com (or the vast majority of third-party content) in an iframe within a modal popup due to their use of `X-Frame-Options` disallowing it.

Comment: Instead of google.com or any third party site if I use my html page then is it possible to do ?

Comment: If you're going to load a page from the same domain as the main page, or from the domain you can control, you've more options than the iframe to load the content.

Comment: @Teemu i dont want to load the page, requirement is have to show that html page as a modal popup when link is clicked

Comment: You still need to load the markup of the page. Whether you should show that other page in an iframe or just in a div, depends on what resources should be loaded. If the page needs its own script(s), it's often easier to load into an iframe, if it's more static, then use AJAX and a div.

Comment: @Teemu is it possible to give me some demo? as I'm very new in this field. it will be helpful for me

Comment: You'd better off if you'd do what Rory said, search for a library and tutorials. And then if you get stuck with the chosen library, ask a specific question about your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Understanding from your question, you are looking how to make a Modal Pop-up which is just on one click in the net:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

If you want a text (h1) to open that popup, you can replace

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

with

```
<h1 type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Best Regards, ykostov

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code.

```js
function show_modal(e)
{
    console.log (e.href);
    $("#iframe_modal").attr("src", e.href);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    return false;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Pop Up Modals</h2>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d7sewLjzNs0" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return show_modal(this);">Open YouTube Video 1</a>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cUMrRYoUZMs" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return show_modal(this);">Open YouTube Video 2</a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe id="iframe_modal" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 40%;"></iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```